# List: Joining three compound items, two with a common element

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, lists

Which one is the most proper way to structure a list comprising "metabolic diseases," "microvascular complications," and "macrovascular complications" in the following example:

High blood glucose increases the risk of

- metabolic diseases, microvascular complications, and macrovascular complications.
- metabolic diseases, microvascular, and macrovascular complications.
- metabolic diseases and microvascular and macrovascular complications.
- metabolic diseases, and microvascular and macrovascular complications.

Comment: (b) is definitely wrong.

Comment: Could you be over-complicating something much more basic than it seems?
 
There are simple rules for lists and they do not understand anything so sophisticated as "microvascular or macrovascular complications…"  If they did, you would prolly be looking at something like "micro- or macrovascular complications."

Does that much make sense?

Comment: @robbiegoodwin I agree that it may seem more complex than it really is. Others also suggested the hyphenated form, but the reason I opted to use the complete forms was that I wanted to follow the AMA style. Anyway, my point was to figure out if using ellipsis would reduce a 3-item list to a 2-item list joined by a conj.: [headache], [kidney  disease], and [heart disease] vs [headache] and [kidney and heart diseases]

Comment: Thanks and no, it would not.

If you want to follow AMA, follow it.

If you have doubts about that, please specify them.

Quite separately is ellipsis matters here, please say how.

If "conj.: [headache], [kidney disease], and [heart disease] vs [headache] and [kidney and heart diseases]" is more useful than a real example, please explain how.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your patience!  Well, I assume we could join (kidney disease) and (heart disease) using the conj. (and) and omit one of the (disease)s in the process [called ellipsis?], thereby turning it to a single unit: (kidney and heart diseases).  Now, if I want to join (headache) to this unit, I will be joining two units one of them already contains an (and), right? Therefore, I would write "x will cause headache and kidney and heart diseases." Please tell me if this is right, and, if not, what is the correct way.

Comment: You asked about joining "three compound items" in a list. Could you explain your idea of the difference between *compound* and *simple* items; how elements in common might matter?

In a sentence, a paragraph or essay any of that might matter.

Please remember, lists are not sentences, paragraphs or essays and in lists, none of that matters.

Your Question seems to be how to merge lists with normal rules of grammar but any useful Answer must point out that that's simply not possible; lists do not follow anything like normal rules… that's why they're called "lists" , not something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option works, as does your last, but I suggest refining the last to give: *metabolic diseases, and micro- and macro-vascular complications*, keeping the Oxford comma but avoiding the repetition in the two related compounds

Answer (score -2):

All are grammatical. However, "c) metabolic diseases and microvascular and macrovascular complications" would do a great favor to the reader.

You may want to hyphenate them as well, and while at it, further simplify:

> High blood glucose increases the risk of metabolic diseases and micro–  and macro-vascular complications.

Comment: I, too, think that (c) is the most correct of the answers. However, I am afraid I can't agree on the grammaticality of all of the items--(b) in particular.